# Strange remote refs for tags

Tags: git

I'm seeing some strange ref names for tags in one of my repos:

```
$ git ls-remote | grep nightly

180641695c1d004c8132a887718365f4180f1105    refs/tags/nightly/1.17.0-GHAnightly.202304040200.1fccacex
1fccace50dac10f8403455f4e8080b26e6318dc7    refs/tags/nightly/1.17.0-GHAnightly.202304040200.1fccacex^{}
9daf0b3c13830720441c93a39aaaeba16f5340b6    refs/tags/nightly/1.17.0-GHAnightly.202304050155.1fccacex
1fccace50dac10f8403455f4e8080b26e6318dc7    refs/tags/nightly/1.17.0-GHAnightly.202304050155.1fccacex^{}
f13e21726ff557c99b02d7e32ed2f304a439c92a    refs/tags/nightly/1.19.0-GHAnightly.202304070158.a22a79fx
a22a79f1967bd10e9ca811106eabf3d6f8cab04a    refs/tags/nightly/1.19.0-GHAnightly.202304070158.a22a79fx^{}
```

Every tag occurs twice, once normally and then again with the strange `^{}` suffix.

There are currently hundreds of nightly tags, and they are all like this, with the strange duplicate. These are created by a script that does `git tag` and the tag name passed to the command is without the `^{}`.

If I look at tags on the `github.com` web site, or in the `git tag`, those weird refs are not there.

In my other repository which is hosted on an internal server, there are no `^{}` refs.

Strange isn't it? Any idea what may be going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected for *annotated tags*. Quoting a parapgraph from [`git help tag`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag) (in the ["Description"](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-tag#_description) section):

> If one of `-a`, `-s`, or `-u <key-id>` is passed, the command creates a tag object, and requires a tag message. Unless `-m <msg>` or `-F <file>` is given, an editor is started for the user to type in the tag message.

For such tags, the tag itself is a separate object in git storage:

```
18064169...    refs/tags/tagname     # <- the tag object
1fccace5...    refs/tags/tagname^{}  # <- the commit it points to
```

If you run `git show` on such a tag, you will see a separate section for the tag itself:

```
tag nightly/1.17.0-GHAnightly.202304040200.1fccacex
Tagger: bob <bob@example.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 17 10:20:27 2021 +0100

The tag message

commit 1fccace50dac10f8403455f4e8080b26e6318dc7 (tag: nightly/1.17.0-GHAnightly.202304040200.1fccacex)
Author: alice <alice@example.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 15 13:43:12 2021 +0100

    The commit message

diff --git ...
```

---

The other kind of tags is called *lightweight tag*, and points directly at a target commit. These are created by running `git tag` without any of the options mentioned above.

In that case, the `^{}` line doesn't exist, and the sha mentioned in the output is directly the commit sha:

```
1fccace5...    refs/tags/lightweighttag   # <- the commit sha
```

If you run `git show` on such a tag you will only see the commit:

```
$ git show lightweighttag
commit 1fccace50dac10f8403455f4e8080b26e6318dc7 (tag: lightweighttag)
Author: alice <alice@example.com>
Date:   Fri Dec 15 13:43:12 2021 +0100

    The commit message

diff --git ...
```

Answer (score -1):

I use [this config](https://gist.github.com/vraravam/eab090e70a545934f409#file-gitconfig-L141) to clean up my orphaned refs, etc. Basically, internally, it just invokes `remote prune`, `repack` and `reflog expire` for ensuring that orphans are not present. I'm not sure if this will help in your case - please try and get back. HTH